# csv helper object reference not set csvWriter c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a class

```
public class avto:IEquatable<avto>
{
    public string gorod;
    public string model;
    public string marka;
    public string god;
    public string cena;
    public string tel1="";
    public string email = "";
    public List<String> tel = new List<string>();
    public avto()
    {

    }
    public void setTel(string t)
    {          
        string[] spl = t.Split(',');
        tel.AddRange(spl);
    }

    public bool Equals(avto other)
    {
        return tel1==other.tel1 && model==other.model && marka==other.marka
            && god==other.god && cena==other.cena && gorod==other.gorod;
    }
}
```

and a code of csvWriter

```
    public void save(List<avto> ls)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter("1.csv"))
        using (var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
        {
            writer.WriteRecords(ls);
        }
    }
```

and on this row

```
writer.WriteRecords(ls);
```

I have error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source-CsvHelper
what can i do to make this code to work?

`Ls` is not null, count=600

Comment: What about **ls**? Please double check the value of ls.

Comment: Provide more code.  From what's currently there, I don't even see how class avto is relevant.

Comment: Assign String.Empty to all string fields. e.g public string gorod=String.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

> The object you're passing into `save(List<avto> ls)` has not been
>   instantiated.

eg:

```
var ls = new List<avto>();
save(ls);
```